# How should you specify a diode?

Tags: power, diodes, power-electronics

If a diode is rated at average forward current at 1 ampere can it stand 1 A from the circuit, or to withstand 1A current should the diode be rated for average forward current of at least 1.5 amperes?

Comment: what circuit???

Comment: You will likely get a much better answer if you include a manufacturer and part number for the diode, as well as a link to the datasheet. Note: you should edit your original question and add that information rather than adding it here in a comment.

Comment: No, just in a general case, if a specific diode (i.e. 1n5819) be able to withstand 1A current through it although it is spec'd at an Average forward current at 1A in the datasheet?

Comment: I glanced at the 1n5819 datasheet. 1A is in the maximum values section. I would advise you not to design right at the maximum for anything. The conditions from note 1 say that the lead temperature must be 90C or less, and the ambient temperature must be 50C or less. So you will have to ascertain if that is realistic for your application. I don't understand why you didn't just edit that information into your question though.

Answer (score 8):

If the diode is rated for 1A it can carry 1A of current under the conditions specified in the datsheet (and as long as you're not violating any of the other specs in the datasheet).

Most engineers in general will want to apply some derating criteria to components, so we don't use a 1A diode to carry 1A, we would pick a 2A diode for a 50% derating for example.

That applies to reverse voltage standoff, power dissipation, peak current, etc.

Your derating depends on your system design goals or specifications if you have them.

Comment: Regarding derating: Of course it also depends on how expensive the next best component is, how expensive a defect is and how stable your operating conditions are.

Answer (score 6):

It may be OK, but there are some things to check.

First, what is the fine print in the datasheet surrounding that rating? Does it apply only when the case temperature is 25C? Or over a certain range of ambient temperatures? Can you maintain those temperatures in your design?

Also, make sure you are looking at something akin to "recommended operating conditions" and not "absolute maximum" or "limiting values." You never want to design so that you are right at the absolute maximum or limiting value.

You kind of need to think like a lawyer reading a contract when you look at a datasheet. Read all the fine print to make sure you understand what information is being conveyed, and any limitations on that information.